# MutationObserver - getting "TypeError: MutationObserver.observe: Argument 1 does not implement interface Node."

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

I'm trying to detect the height of an element set dynamically by an image slider plugin and use it to set the height of a container.

Getting "TypeError: MutationObserver.observe: Argument 1 does not implement interface Node."

I checked [MutationObserver documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and [its options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit). Saw that

> At a minimum, one of childList, attributes, and/or characterData must be true when you call observe(). Otherwise, a TypeError exception will be thrown.

and I am setting attributes to true but still getting the typeError

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
      for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
          console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
      }
  };

  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  //set up your configuration
  const config = { attributes:true, subtree: false };

  var changingContainer = $('.soliloquy-viewport');

  //start observing
  observer.observe(changingContainer, config);
  
  //change height on button press
  function changeHeight(){
    changingContainer.height(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 20));
  }
  $("#height").click(changeHeight);
});
```

```css
.soliloquy-viewport{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="soliloquy-viewport">
  Hello
</div>
<button id="height">
change height
</button>
```

Comment: jQuery object is not what is expected as an argument, try `var changingContainer = $('.soliloquy-viewport').get(0)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : thanks, confused `.eq()` and `.get()`, it's been a long time since I used jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MutationObervers only work on an Element object, not jQuery objects. Change the first argument of the `observe()` to the underlying Element by using `get()` like this:

```
observer.observe(changingContainer.get(0), config);
```

Or by accessing the jQuery object by index like this:

```
observer.observe(changingContainer[0], config);
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let $changingContainer = $('.soliloquy-viewport');
  
  const observer = new MutationObserver((ml, o) => {
    for (const m of ml) {
      console.log('The ' + m.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
    }
  });
  
  observer.observe($changingContainer.get(0), {
    attributes: true,
    subtree: false
  });

  //change height on button press
  $("#height").click(() => $changingContainer.height(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 20)));
});
```

```css
.soliloquy-viewport {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="soliloquy-viewport">Hello</div>
<button id="height">change height</button>
```

Note that this only works for a single element. For multiple elements with the same class, you will need to loop through them and apply the MO individually.